# React-native fbsdk-next asks just for public_profile permission

Tags: react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I have next issue: my react-native app doesn't ask fb about all permissions from list, just about public_profile permission. System iOS.
My code is:

```
LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'user_posts', 'email']).then(
  (result) => {
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      alert('Login was cancelled')
    } else {
      console.log("RESULT_IS", result)
      AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then((data) => {
        const accessToken = data.accessToken.toString();
        const userID = data.userID.toString();
      });
      Profile.getCurrentProfile().then((data) => {
        console.log('DATA', data);
      })
    }
  },
);
```

console.log('DATA', data) shows that imageURL, userID and name has a value, and email, firstName, lastName, middleName are null.
console.log("RESULT_IS", result) shows RESULT_IS {"declinedPermissions": [], "grantedPermissions": ["public_profile"], "isCancelled": false}

So I am using Profile.getCurrentProfile() to get additional data from fb (for example email). To do that I asked fb about additional permissions adding them to LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(). As I understood my app doesn't ask about fb all permissions just about public_profile. Why does it happened and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue too.
On Android, in the path below

```
node_modules/react-native fbsdk-next/android/src/main/java/com/facebook/reactnative/androidsdk/FBProfileModule.java
```

You can import profile information right away by editing the file as shown below.
I also referenced other people's content.
So have a nice day!

FBProfileModule.java

```java
package com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk;

import com.facebook.Profile;
import com.facebook.ProfileTracker; // add
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.module.annotations.ReactModule;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

/**
 * This is a {@link NativeModule} that allows JS to use FBSDKProfile info of the current logged user.    
    + * current logged user // add
 */
@ReactModule(name = FBProfileModule.NAME)
public class FBProfileModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    public static final String NAME = "FBProfile";    
    private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker; // add

    public FBProfileModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
      super(reactContext);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
    return NAME;
  }

    /**
    * Get the current logged profile.
    * @param callback Use callback to pass the current logged profile back to JS.
    */
    @ReactMethod
    public void getCurrentProfile(Callback callback) {
        //Return the profile object as a ReactMap.
        // add
      if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
        mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
          @Override
          protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile currentProfile) {
            callback.invoke(Utility.profileToReactMap(currentProfile));
            mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
          }
        };
      } else {
        callback.invoke(Utility.profileToReactMap(Profile.getCurrentProfile()));
      }

    // remove
        // callback.invoke(Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null
        //         ? null
        //         : Utility.profileToReactMap(Profile.getCurrentProfile()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provides public profile by default if you want anything else you will have to add it by visiting your app in facebook developer console.

1. Go to your app
2. Open app Review
3. In app review open Permissions and Features
4. In Permissions and Features you can see multiple options

Select your desired permission and try again you will get that value as well.

I hope it helps you.